# Nested selection with Update

Tags: d3.js

I've built what I think is the most current solution for a [nested selection](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) with an [update pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218).

However, each time update is clicked, I always get the outer selection, but not always the inner (nested) selection. The log to console show a correctly formed array of arrays.

Is this the correct setup for a nested selection in v5?
[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/sansSpoon/pen/oyWoeL)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>#</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .outer {
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: grey;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .inner {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      background-color: cyan;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <button id='update'>update</button>
  <div id="anchor"></div>
  <script>
    const updateButton = document.getElementById('update');
    const anchor = d3.select('#anchor');

    updateButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      update(
        Array.from({
          length: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5)
        }, function() {
          return Array.from({
            length: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5)
          }, function() {
            return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
          });
        })
      );
    });


    function update(data) {

      const outer = anchor.selectAll('.outer').data(data);

      outer.exit().remove();

      outer.enter()
        .append('div')
        .merge(outer)
        .attr("class", "outer");

      const inner = outer.selectAll('.inner').data(function(d) {
        return d;
      });

      inner.exit().remove();

      inner.enter()
        .append('div')
        .merge(inner)
        .attr("class", "inner")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d;
        });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a case like this one you have to *reassign* the update selection, so its reference is merged with the enter selection (here I'm changing `const` for `let` in order to reassign the selection):

```
//here is the update selection:
let outer = anchor.selectAll('.outer').data(data);

//here is the enter selection:
const outerEnter = outer.enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr("class", "outer");

//reassigning here: 
outer = outerEnter.merge(outer);
```

Otherwise `other` will be only the update selection, even if you have a `merge` method chained in the enter selection. You can clearly see this if you console `outer.size()`.

Here is your code with that change:

```js
const updateButton = document.getElementById('update');
const anchor = d3.select('#anchor');

updateButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  update(
    Array.from({
      length: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5)
    }, function() {
      return Array.from({
        length: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5)
      }, function() {
        return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
      });
    })
  );
});


function update(data) {
  let outer = anchor.selectAll('.outer').data(data);

  outer.exit().remove();

  const outerEnter = outer.enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr("class", "outer");

  outer = outerEnter.merge(outer);

  const inner = outer.selectAll('.inner').data(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

  inner.exit().remove();

  inner.enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr("class", "inner")
    .merge(inner)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    });
}
```

```css
 .outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
 }
 .inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<button id='update'>update</button>
<div id="anchor"></div>
```